# How can I execute a query based on the result of another query? (Express, NodeJS, mysql)

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, node-mysql

I am trying to generate a session ID when an API call is made to my 'generateSession' endpoint. I want to make sure that I don't have any duplicate session ID, so I query the database checking for a match on the generated ID. If there isn't a match, the ID is valid and I make a second query to add an active user with said session ID.

Although my first query executes, the 'id_is_valid' boolean never gets set to true so my program gets stuck in the while loop.

I am fairly new to JavaScript, but from some research, I'm pretty sure the problem is due to the asynchronous nature of the database call. However, I'm not sure where to go from there. Could anyone with more js knowledge offer me some direction?

Thanks!

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var myDB = require('../db-connection');

function generateSession() {
    var session_id = '';
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) session_id += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return session_id;
}

router.get('/generateSession', function(req, res){
    var session_id = '';
    var id_is_valid = false;
    while (!id_is_valid){
        session_id = generateSession();

        myDB.query("SELECT * FROM activeUser WHERE session_id = ?", [session_id], function(error, results, field){
            if(error) throw error;
            else{
                if (results.length === 0) is_is_valid = true;
            }
        });
    }

    myDB.query("INSERT INTO activeUser (is_registered, session_id) VALUES (0, ?)", [session_id], function(error, results, fields){
        if (error) res.send('{"success": false}');
        else res.send('{"success": true, "session_id": "' + session_id + '"}');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although my first query executes, the id_is_valid boolean never gets set to true so my program gets stuck in the while loop.

This is because db call, by nature is asynchronous. If you run the following program you will know it.

```
'use strict';

let id_is_valid = false;
let count = 0;

while (!id_is_valid) {
  count++;
  console.log(`No of time setTimeout Invoked ${count}`);
  setTimeout(function() { // simulating a db call that takes a second for execution
    id_is_valid = true;
  }, 1000);
}

console.log('This line wont be printed');
```

**Outputs**

> No of time setTimeout Invoked 61415
>   No of time setTimeout Invoked 61416
>   No of time setTimeout Invoked 61417
>   ^C //I killed it.

Like damitj07, I too suggest using npms like [`shortId`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) for uniquely generating the sessionId. This will help you to eliminate a database call.
But if your business logic restricts and you need it in the current fashion you wrote. I think we can use `async` & `await`

```
'use strict';

let isFound = false;
let count = 0;

function doDbQuery() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(true);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function run() {
  while (!isFound) {
    count++;
    console.log(`No of time setTimeout Invoked ${count}`);
    isFound = await doDbQuery();
  }
  console.log('This line WILL BE printed');
}

run();
```

**Output**

> No of time setTimeout Invoked 1
>   This line WILL BE printed

Making those changes to your code,

```
router.get('/generateSession', async function (req, res) {
  var session_id = '';
  var id_is_valid = false;
  while (!id_is_valid) {
    session_id = generateSession();
    id_is_valid = await checkSessionIdInDb(session_id);
  }

  myDB.query('INSERT INTO activeUser (is_registered, session_id) VALUES (0, ?)', [session_id], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      res.send('{"success": false}');
    } else {
      res.send('{"success": true, "session_id": "' + session_id + '"}');
    }
  });
});

function checkSessionIdInDb() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myDB.query('SELECT * FROM activeUser WHERE session_id = ?', [session_id], function (error, results, field) {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      } else {
        if (results.length === 0) {
          resolve(true);
        }
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could make out of your code what you want to do is basically create a new user session for logged in user with a unique session Id, also making sure that the session ID does not already exist in the collection.

So the solution to this can be to the first query to check if the session ID is already present in Active_Users Collection, if not make a save call to save the user with generated session Id.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var myDB = require('../db-connection');

function generateSession() {
    var session_id = '';
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) session_id += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return session_id;
}

router.get('/generateSession', function(req, res) {
    var session_id = '';

    myDB.query("SELECT * FROM activeUser WHERE session_id = ?", [session_id], function(error, results, field) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            if (results.length === 0) {
                //if session id is not present , insert new user
                session_id = generateSession();
                myDB.query("INSERT INTO activeUser (is_registered, session_id) VALUES (0, ?)", [session_id], function(error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) res.send('{"success": false}');
                    else res.send('{"success": true, "session_id": "' + session_id + '"}');
                });
            }
            //else do nothing or inser nothing
        }
    });

});
```

But Ideally, if you are generating a truly random session id each time when you make a request to the `/generate` session, is it really necessary to check for duplicates in the collection.
Now if the logic to generate a random ID is not perfect, you can always use modules like [shortId](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) to do the work for you. This will avoid unnecessary database call and save on performance and your code will be much neater.

Comment: I guess my solution will work well with both cases, and much better if you use the shortId , it will avoid an extra DB call.

Comment: On the off chance that the randomly generated session id is already in use, I don't want to do nothing... I want to generate another and another until I generate one that isn't in use. I suppose I could have the client make another api call to generateSession if it returns a failure message... however that feels like an unnecessary workaround

Comment: Well if you use a  module which generates these Id's for you then, you can be sure the off chance goes to 0.  If you read through the shortId documentation I think you will get the idea how much safe that is., anyway I hope I helped you solve your problem.  You can accept the answer if so.